# Passing variables from AngularJS service to controller with Google API?

Tags: angularjs, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to use the Google API Javascript client to utilize Google Login on my app, and then access the user's email address and contacts. I'm combining this with AngularJS, and I've read that it's best to make this its own Service.

Here is the code for the service so far:

```
.service('googleLogin', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
            var clientId = '{MY CLIENT KEY}',
                apiKey = '{MY API KEY}',
                scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds',
                domain = '{MY COMPANY DOMAIN}';

            this.handleClientLoad = function () {
                // Step 2: Reference the API key
                gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
                gapi.auth.init(function () { });
                window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
            };

            this.checkAuth = function() {
                gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true, hd: domain }, this.handleAuthResult );
            };

            this.handleAuthResult = function(authResult) {
                if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                    gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
                        var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();
                        request.execute(function (resp) {
                            console.log(userEmail);
                        });
                    });
                }
            };

            this.handleAuthClick = function (event) {
                // Step 3: get authorization to use private data
                gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false, hd: domain }, this.handleAuthResult );
                return false;
            };

        }]);
```

I then call this from the controller with the following:

```
        $scope.login = function () {
            googleLogin.handleAuthClick();
        };
```

Which works, and the API is called properly. But now, I'm not sure how to get data from the API through the Service. I need to get the user's email address, as well as a list of their contacts. I can't just have separate `get` functions that return these values, because it seems like the API client calls must be made in chains (for example, `handleAuthResult` is called as a parameter in `handleAuthClick`).

I've also tried setting them as `$rootScope` values, or just normal variables, but once the controller calls them they always come as `undefined`.

Am I approaching this correctly? How can I get these variables from the Google API, to the Service, to the Controller? Thanks.

Comment: What does the `handleClientLoad` method do? It looks like that's the initialization routine. Is that automatically called when the singleton service loads?

Comment: @JimG. I wrote this code a long time ago now, and it does look like it'd be an initialization routine but it definitely is not being called anywhere. May be superfluous/unnecessary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using the promise/defer implementation from angularJS, documented [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q).

Here's the final service:

```
.service('googleLogin', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$q', function ($http, $rootScope, $q) {
            var clientId = '{MY CLIENT ID}',
                apiKey = '{MY API KEY}',
                scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds',
                domain = '{MY COMPANY DOMAIN}',
                userEmail,
                deferred = $q.defer();

            this.login = function () {
                gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false, hd: domain }, this.handleAuthResult);

                return deferred.promise;
            }

            this.handleClientLoad = function () {
                gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
                gapi.auth.init(function () { });
                window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
            };

            this.checkAuth = function() {
                gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true, hd: domain }, this.handleAuthResult );
            };

            this.handleAuthResult = function(authResult) {
                if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                    var data = {};
                    gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
                        var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();
                        request.execute(function (resp) {
                            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                                data.email = resp.email;
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                } else {
                    deferred.reject('error');
                }
            };

            this.handleAuthClick = function (event) {
                gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false, hd: domain }, this.handleAuthResult );
                return false;
            };

        }]);
```

And how it's currently called in the controller:

```
var promise = googleLogin.login();
                promise.then(function (data) {
                    console.log(data.email);
                }, function (reason) {
                    console.log('Failed: ' + reason);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this way :

public Credential authenticate() throws IOException {
try {
Credential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(scopes);
System.out.println("Loaded the Application Default Credentials.");
return credential;
} catch (IOException e) {
// No need to do anything, we'll fall back on other credentials.
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).